# SQL function in Hibernate insert statement

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

How do include a function like `getdate()` in an insert statement for Hibernate query?

Lets say one of the properties of a mapped class is a `datetime` column how do put specify `getdate()` in order for the `.save()` method call to use the server timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is don't include it in the insert statement and let SQL do it.

In the SQL table designer where you have the date column you are inserting into, set the Default Value to `GETDATE()` in the column properties and SQL Server will handle it for you.

Reference and sample: [SQL Server GETDATE() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_getdate.asp)

Table create script will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```