# IntelliJ IDEA code inspection: HQL custom dialect & registered functions

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, hql, code-inspection

My question is about

1. using registered functions for date/time manipulations in Hibernate Query Language and
2. IntelliJ IDEA's code inspection for these registered functions in HQL.

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.5 with Java 7, and SQL Server 2008 R2 as the database, and IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6.

In an HQL query I need to perform the TSQL DATEADD function - or the equivalent HQL date operation. This doesn't seem to exist.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
update MyTable set startTime = GETDATE(), targetTime = DATEADD(HOUR, allocatedTime, GETDATE()), endTime = null where faultReport.faultReportId = :faultReportId and slaTypeId = :slaTypeId
```

Searching for answers online has been disappointingly no help, and the most common advice (like the comment seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150333/2753571) seems to be "don't use date manipulation in hql." I don't see how I can get around performing the operation in the SQL statement in the general case (e.g. when you want to update one column based on the value in another column in multiple rows).

In a similar fashion to the advice in this post: [Date operations in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568914/date-operations-in-hql), I've subclassed a SQLServerDialect implementation and registered new functions:

```
registerFunction("get_date", new NoArgSQLFunction("GETDATE", StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP)); // this function is a duplication of "current_timestamp" but is here for testing / illustration
registerFunction("add_hours", new VarArgsSQLFunction(TimestampType.INSTANCE, "DATEADD(HOUR,", ",", ")"));
```

and added this property to my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="my.project.dialect.SqlServerDialectExtended" />
```

and then I'm testing with a simple (meaningless, admitted) query like this:

```
select x, get_date(), add_hours(1, get_date()) from MyTable x
```

The functions appear to be successfully registered, and that query seems to be working because the following SQL is generated and the results are correct:

```
select
    faultrepor0_.FaultReportSLATrackingId as col_0_0_,
    GETDATE() as col_1_0_,
    DATEADD(HOUR,
    1,
    GETDATE()) as col_2_0_,
    ... etc.
```

But I now have this problem with IntelliJ IDEA: where get_date() is used in the HQL, the code inspection complains "<expression> expected, got ')'". This is marked as an error and the file is marked in red as a compilation failure.

Can someone can explain how to deal with this, please, or explain what a better approach is? Am I using the incorrect SQLFunction template (VarArgsSQLFunction)? If yes, which is the best one to use?

I'd like the usage of the registered function to not be marked as invalid in my IDE. Ideally, if someone can suggest a better way altogether than creating a new dialect subclass, that would be awesome.

Comment: Update: Problem solved.

Turns out it's really easy in IDEA to resolve this: place the caret over your HQL/JPQL/TSQL etc., press Alt+Enter, then select "Language Injection Settings." You can select a language in the dialog which appears. Would delete this question, but maybe it will help someone else who searches for the same advice, in the future..